# How to install 'readline' with Cabal on Windows

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I would like to install 'readline' using Cabal on Windows. When running the command it is saying that readline isn't found. Cabal is up to date.

Command

```
cabal install readline
```

Output

```
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.cabal-sandbox
Configuring readline-1.0.3.0...
Failed to install readline-1.0.3.0
Build log ( C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\haskell-project\.cabal-sandbox\logs\readline-1.0.3.0.log ):
Configuring readline-1.0.3.0...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for GNUreadline.framework... checking for readline... no
checking for tputs in -lncurses... no
checking for tputs in -ltermcap... no
checking for tputs in -lcurses... no
checking for rl_readline_version... no
configure: error: readline not found, so this package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
readline-1.0.3.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Looks like its an OS mismatch. You're running windows, GNU readline is probably only included on POSIX systems. Have you tried building/installing the [GNU readline application for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm)?

Comment: Just installed it and tried it out. The same error occurs.

Comment: Doesn't seem like readline is officially supported on windows. The homepage says it has to be installed through cygwin.

Comment: Okay I'll have a look at installing it through that tonight and see how I go thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an msys distro that includes `pacman` (the one that ships with the windows haskell platform installer should be such a distro) then you can use `pacman` to install the readline library, and this *should* let you link against it.

Also note that ghc ships with the `haskeline` library, which is a pure-haskell replacement for readline that is more portable.