# Process arrow key ANSI escape sequences on haskell stdin

Tags: haskell, stdin, ansi-escape

I'm trying to process arrow key ANSI escape sequences i.e.

```
up - "\033[A"
down - "\033[B"
left - "\033[D"
right - "\033[C"
```

in my programme so when I press the up/down/left/right arrow key, it won't have to look like this:

```
% stack runghc test.hs
Input a name?
^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D^
```

on my stdin, but rather I would like those keys to be suppressed or even better,
for them to actually work(i.e move the cursor left/right). My code is as follows:

```
main = do putStrLn "Input a name?"  
          name <- getLine  
          putStrLn $ ("His name is " ++ name)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @bradrn I'm using macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble installing the `readline` library due to some [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142369/how-to-install-readline-with-cabal-on-windows) and decided to use the [haskeline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.8.1.1/docs/System-Console-Haskeline.html) library, which is a more portable pure-haskell replacement for it.

Using its syntax and modifying the earlier code, I got:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do putStrLn "Input a name?"
          runInputT defaultSettings insertion
  where
      insertion :: InputT IO ()
      insertion = do
          minput <- getInputLine ""
          case minput of
              Nothing -> return ()
              Just input -> do outputStrLn $ "His name is " ++ input
```

Which solves the problem as I am now able to move my cursor with the arrow keys freely without having to see any trailing ANSI escape sequences as shown below:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get readline-like functionality is to just use readline. For most simple use cases, `rlwrap` is good enough, as described in [One REPL to bind them all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5639502/625403). If you need to do fancier integrations, you can use the [readline](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/readline-1.0.3.0/docs/System-Console-Readline.html) package.